# Angularjs Validation is not working when it first time

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angularjs and  i am trying to validate while submitting a form, it is not working , but when i fill first input field and then submit it works and then again after clearing that field its all clear how to resolve this problem of validation.

Here is my html page

```
<form name="addAlbumForm" novalidate>
<div class="album panel panel-default" >

    <div class="panel panel-heading">
    <!-- <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-show="addAlbumForm.date.$error.minlength">Date Too short</div> -->
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-show="addAlbumForm_error">{{addAlbumForm_error}}</div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Title...." size="20" ng-model="adding_album.title" style="width: 130px;"/>
        <div class="panel-title" style="float: right">
          <input type="text" name="date" ng-minlength="10" ng-required="true" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd" size="10" ng-model="adding_album.date">
        </div>

    </div>
     <p>
    <div class="description">
    <p>
      <textarea ng-model="adding_album.description" placeholder="
      Description..." rows="4" style="width:100%"></textarea>
       </p>
       <p> <input type="text" placeholder="Name..." size="10" ng-model="adding_album.name"></p>
    </div>
    </p>

    <p >
      <button type="button" ng-click="addAlbum(adding_album)" class="btn btn-success"> Add New Albums</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

Here is my controller

```
    MyApp.controller('AlbumListController', function($scope){
      $scope.albums =[{ name: 'anand123', title: 'Weekend in Moderil',date:'12-01-2016',description :'abdkabkjasajsk sdsdsds dfdsfsdfsd '}] 
  $scope.addAlbum=function(new_album){
    if(!new_album.title)
      $scope.addAlbumForm_error= "Missing Title!";
    else if(!new_album.date || new_album.date.length <10)
       $scope.addAlbumForm_error= "Invalid Date!";
     else if(!new_album.description || new_album.description <10)
       $scope.addAlbumForm_error= "Description Too Short!";
     else if(!new_album.name)
       $scope.addAlbumForm_error= "Missing Name!";
     else{
        $scope.albums.push(new_album);
        $scope.adding_album={};
     }

  }

});
```

I got an error that **Can not read property 'title' of undefined**, but once I fill title then it starts working properly and i have also cleared the title filed.

Answer (score 1):

I just add the form using ng-init
ex:

```
<form ng-init="adding_album={}; addAlbumForm_error=''">
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try using ng-init in the form tag, initialize your variables such as `adding_album` as {} and `addAlbumForm_error` as false

for eg: 

`<form ng-init="adding_album='{}'; addAlbumForm_error=false">`

Comment: Initial problem is solved but after adding this code i cant type anything in this title text box

Comment: adding_album is not a string i just edit your code like this i got solution <form ng-init="adding_album={}; addAlbumForm_error=''"> thank you